# Polymer paper-header-panel won't render properly

Tags: polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0

I posted kinda similar problem here in StackOverFlow regarding paper-header-panel of Polymer it was answered but the solution isn't efficient or right way of doing it, you can look it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103073/the-paper-header-panel-or-the-paper-drawer-panel-wont-take-the-whole-top-edges). Specific import should be made not the generic one as mentioned [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/paper-styles.html#L33).

My code for rendering it properly is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">

</head>

<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <!-- paper-header-panel must have an explicit height -->
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
        <paper-toolbar>
            <div>Header</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div>Content</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Proper Rendering]

But the problem is that this import is already been deprecated.

```
<link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

The documentations recommended to use the new class which is.

```
<link rel="import"
          href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
```

But it doesn't render properly the paper-header-panel.

[image: Problematic Rendering]

What did I miss? Or what is my mistake? Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html

> A set of layout classes that let you specify layout properties directly in markup.
>
> You must include this file in every element that needs to use them.
>   Sample use:
>
> ```
> <link rel="import" href="../iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
> <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
> <div class="layout horizontal layout-start">
>   <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> The following imports are available:
>
> - iron-flex
> - iron-flex-reverse
> - iron-flex-alignment
> - iron-flex-factors
> - iron-positioning

You'd only have to include the `iron-flex` and `iron-positioning` style modules for your use case.

Ex.

```
<link rel="import" href="../iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-positioning"></style>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <!-- paper-header-panel must have an explicit height -->
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
        <paper-toolbar>
            <div>Header</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div>Content</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
</body>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I'll take note of this in the future.